# Making a metric out of distance measure

Tags: trigonometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I'm working with a pseudo-distance measure that is not a metric since it does not hold the triangle inequality. It is called [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).

The problem is - I need to perform some projections, so I need to make triangle inequality hold for my distance measure. If I understand correctly, I need to *embed* it into metric space.

How can I do that, if possible? I'm not a mathematician, so could some one explain the problem to me and how to overcome it?

In the original [paperwork](https://seer.lcc.ufmg.br/index.php/jidm/article/viewFile/99/82) it says

```
Second, the distances: xi are exact only if the metric space can be embedded in an Euclidean space
```

How to perform this embedding?

Thanks

Comment: The linked paper talks about embedding a metric space into a Euclidean space. That is different from making a metric from a pseudo-distance. To obtain a metric that is somehow related to a pseudo-distance, one has to study the specific situation and objectives; in practical terms, you need someone knowledgeable in this area to be on your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand. But how can I embed a metric space into a Euclidean space, then?